# AbstractMethodError When using Jboss5 and Hibernate 4

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, jboss5.x

I am trying to Upgrade my Spring 1.9 Application to Spring 4 and therefore I also have to upgrade Hibernate. As database I am using Oracle.

When starting the application everything is fine until I am using Clobs, then the following Exception is thrown:

`java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk5.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK5.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V`

I also already upgradet my JDBC driver, does anyone have hint, what else to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the *jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar* located under `${JBOSS_HOME}\common\lib` obviously it was implemented against an Interface which was created in a version which is less then JDK_1.6. Therefore the method was never implemented though.

After replacing this Jar, with the same vom a JBoss AS 6.1 everything is working fine.

BR